# Save photo to UIImageView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

The app is supposed to take/select a picture then assign it to an image view. Everything seems to work but the image view never changes. My code:

```
- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender
{
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
// Lazily allocate image picker controller
if (!imagePickerController) {
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    // If our device has a camera, we want to take a picture, otherwise, we just pick from
    // photo library
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    }else
    {
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    }
}
// Place image picker on the screen
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [imagePickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    imagePickerPopover = nil;
}

UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

[imageView setImage:image];
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're not setting the delegate for the image picker, For instance:  `[imagePickerController setDelegate:self];` I think that would be in your `takePicture` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need a delegate. Add:

```
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
```